# Can there be transfer of mass in a system without any transfer of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

While the mass-energy equivalence might be able to prevent this , considering the  thermodynamic definition of energy where it is treated separately from mass , can this be possible ? If so , can you give me an example of such a system ?

Comment: No. But you can maintain total energy of the system constant after addition of mass by appropriate amount of heat transfer out of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Just to cover both sources of energy that you might be thinking of.

If you transfer mass, say by pouring 5 litres of water into a bucket already containing water, the kinetic energy of the inflowing water is transferred into an increase in the internal energy of the system.

If you mean an increase in the rest mass energy of the system, the equivalency principle is well, unequivocal about this. Mass **is** energy so  either way, if mass goes into a system, the energy associated with it (of all types) will also enter the system.